# Dynamic Ajax filter with Laravel implementation

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

i'm tryng to create a sidebar filters for an e-commerce. I have successfully implemented a infinte scroll pagination, but now i have a problem with filters.

```
    <ul class="check-box-list">
      <?php $m = 1; ?>
        @foreach($marchi as $marchio)
          <li>
           <input type="checkbox" id="m{{$m}}" class="marchio" name="{{ $marchio->id_produttore }}" data-marchio="{{ $marchio->brand->nome}}" value="{{ $marchio->brand->nome }}" />
          <label for="m{{$m}}">
            <span class="button"></span>
               {{ $marchio->id_produttore }}<span class="count">({{ $marchio->total }})</span>
            </label>   
     </li>
 <?php $m++; ?>
     @endforeach   
 </ul>
```

have this above checkboxes that is generated dynamically.
If i click on one of this i can trigger the correct value using this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.marchio').on('click', function() {
      var marchio = $('.marchio:checked').val();
      $.ajax(
        {
            url: '?marchio=' + marchio,
            type: "get",
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.ajax-load').show();
            }
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            if(data.html == " "){
                $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
                return;
            }
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $("#post-data").append(data.html);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('server not responding...');
        });
});
```

But if i click a 2nd checkbox, the value appended to the ajax url remaining the same, if i uncheck the first remaining the second. I need to pass to the url multiple values of the same checkbox class by appending it to the url.
And if some categorie's can have multiple filter's i need the ajax url can accept different ?querystryngs for example by appending ',' separated values once we click on checkboxes. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax call you can do something like this:

```
$('.marchio').on('click', function () {
    var marchi = {};

    $('.marchio:checked').each(function () {
        marchi[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'get',

        // This is the important part!
        data: {marchi: marchi}
    })
});
```

This will send a request like so:

```
http://example.com/?marchi[name1]=value1&marchi[name2]=value2
```

In PHP, this is just converted into an array, so you can simply do this in your controller:

```
foreach (Request::get('marchi') as $id_produttore => $brandNome) {
    // This marchio has been selected.
}
```

If you want to pass in more values, you can simply add more to the `data` property of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Wow JOE, you're great. Many, many, many, many thks, work as well, and i have learned one new important concept.